# Find Top Most AND Lowest In a Table's Group Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table and there are 4 fields in it, `ID, Price, QTY, Ratting` and Optional [Position].

I have all the records Grouped By Columns `[Qty,Ratting]`

I have to define the position of groupwise and store that Position into Optional column.

For better understanding I have added an image with data in table:

[image]

On the basis of `QTY` in Each `Rating` I have to Mark `Top3, Bottom3 and Rest of them as remaining.`

I am not getting how to do it.

Can anybody suggest me how to do it?
So far what I've tried is:

```
Declare @RankTable TABLE 
(
    ID INT,
    Price Decimal (10,2),
    Qty INT,
    Ratting INT
)
INSERT INTO @RankTable 
SELECT 1,10,15,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,11,11,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,96,10,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,96,8,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,56,7,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,74,5,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 7,93,4,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 8,98,2,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 9,12,1,1

UNION ALL
SELECT 10,32,80,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 11,74,68,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 12,58,57,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 13,37,43,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 14,79,32,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 15,29,28,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 16,46,17,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 17,86,13,2

UNION ALL
SELECT 19,75,110,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 20,27,108,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 21,38,104,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 22,87,100,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 23,47,89,3
DECLARE @PositionGroup VARCHAR(1)
SELECT *,ISNULL(@PositionGroup,'') AS Position FROM @RankTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT ID
      ,Price
      ,Qty
      ,Ratting
      ,CASE WHEN RowID >= 1 AND RowID <= 3 
            THEN 0 
       ELSE CASE WHEN RowID > Total - 3 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END END AS Position
FROM (SELECT ID
            ,Price
            ,Qty
            ,Ratting
            ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Ratting) AS Total
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ratting ORDER BY Qty DESC) AS RowID
            ,ISNULL(@PositionGroup,'') AS Position
      FROM @RankTable) AS T
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Window Function`. Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY rating ORDER BY id)         rn,
                count(id)OVER(partition BY rating) mx
         FROM   @RankTable)
SELECT ID,
       Price,
       Qty,
       Rating,
        mx - rn,
       CASE WHEN rn IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) THEN 0
            WHEN mx - rn IN( 0, 1, 2 ) THEN 1
         ELSE 2
       END position
FROM   cte
```

Answer (score 0):

try this as well.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT  MAX(Row) [Max],
        MIN(Row) [Min],
        LU.Ratting 
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ratting ORDER BY Qty DESC) Row 
        FROM    @RankTable)LU
        GROUP BY LU.Ratting
        ) 

SELECT  ID,
        R.Price,
        R.Qty,
        cte.Ratting,
        CASE WHEN (Row - Min) <= 2 THEN 0 WHEN (Max - Row) <= 2 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END Position 
FROM    cte 
JOIN    (
        SELECT  Ratting,
                ID,
                Price,
                Qty,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Ratting ORDER BY Qty DESC) [Row] 
        FROM    @RankTable
        ) R ON R.Ratting = cte.Ratting
```

Result:

[image]